# Django: disallow can_delete on GenericStackedInline

Tags: python, django, django-admin, generics, formset

I've built this model which contains a generic foreign key:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, verbose_name=_('content type'))
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('object id'))
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Next I've made a generic stacked inline to put it in any ModelAmin class:

```
class MyModelStackedInline(generic.GenericStackedInline):
    model = MyModel
    formset = generic.generic_inlineformset_factory(MyModel, can_delete=False)
    extra = 0

class SomeOhterModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [MyModelStackedInline]
```

However, despite the can_`delete=False` arg passed by in generic_inlineformset_factory, I always see a `Delete` checkbox in my admin change_form.

Here is an example: http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/3323/screenshotbe.png

Do you know how to remove this checkbox ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update 2016: as per Stan's answer below, modern versions of django let you set [`can_delete = True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.can_delete) on the [`GenericStackedInline`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.admin.GenericStackedInline) subclass, as it inherits from [`InlineModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.can_delete)

---

I've run into this before - for some reason passing can_delete as an argument doesn't work, but setting it in the formset's **init** method does. Try this:

```
class MyInlineFormset(generic.generic_inlineformset_factory(MyModel)):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyInlineFormset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.can_delete = False
```

then in your admin inline class:

```
class MyModelStackedInline(generic.GenericStackedInline):
    model = MyModel
    formset = MyInlineFormset
    extra = 0
```

Comment: Sorry for answering so (very) late. It's now working. I will probably open a new ticket on django website about it. Thank you. ;-)

Answer (score 45):

Maybe It is a post '09 feature, but you can specify that without overriding the `__init__()` method :

```
class StupidCarOptionsInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = models.StupidOption
    form = StupidCarOptionAdminForm
    extra = 0
    can_delete = False
```

Comment: "can_delete = False" was just what I was looking for.

Comment: This is the best anwer